# How to use a method from a generic object list iterator to call another class' equals method

Tags: java, list, object, compare, equals

I am taking an intro to Java course, and we are learning about how to make a generic object list iterator (I call it List) that can be extended into more specific lists later. This way, if I decide to make another list class later on, I can just extend List instead of going through typing all the getters, setters, insert(), delete(), etc. again.

My professor wants our List class to have an isThere() method. She wants it to accept an object, iterate through the list until it finds a match, and then return the index of where it found it. I have searched for similar questions on this site, but most of the methods suggested include "<>", or hash which we are not allowed to use in this class. We are also not allowed to use any Array method that java provides for us. We must write our own methods.

So, my problem is that I have stored 10 Users in my Object List. I intentionally stored one element as "Bimmy" so that I could try to find that element using my isThere() method. When I went through debug mode, it shows that it reaches the User method equals() and then returns false. Debug also shows that the User's names are both "Bimmy" and the id values are also the same (Users having the same name and id are the requirements for the equals method to return true).

Again, this is my first semester taking Java, and I think my problem has to do with casting. I think that in the List's isThere(), "list[i]" doesn't know that it is a User, or that it should compare itself to the other User object. However, I am really not sure. If anyone would be so kind as to help, I would greatly appreciate it. I will post the code below...

List isThere() method:

```
public int isThere(Object obj)
    {
        for(int i = 0; i<index; i++)
        {
            if(list[i].equals(obj))
            {
                return i;
            }
        }

            return -1;
    }
```

The User's equal() method:

```
public boolean equals(User user)
{
    if(user.getName().equals(name) && user.getId().equals(id))
    {
        return true;
    }
    else
        return false;
}
```

This is what I am doing in Main:

```
System.out.println("-----------------------------test isThere()");
    UserList check = new UserList(10);
    check.tryAdd(new User("Jimmy", "562801"));//I am adding 10 Users here.
    check.tryAdd(new User("Jimmy", "562801"));//I put one as "Bimmy" so that I can 
    check.tryAdd(new User("Jimmy", "562801"));//test this method to find that User
    check.tryAdd(new User("Jimmy", "562801"));//at index 8
    check.tryAdd(new User("Jimmy", "562801"));
    check.tryAdd(new User("Jimmy", "562801"));
    check.tryAdd(new User("Jimmy", "562801"));
    check.tryAdd(new User("Jimmy", "562801"));
    check.tryAdd(new User("Bimmy", "562801"));
    check.tryAdd(new User("Jimmy", "562801"));
    System.out.println(check.toString());


    System.out.println(check.isThere( new User("Bimmy","562801")));
```

At this point the console outputs -1 meaning "Bimmy" was not found. I am not sure how to fix this problem, but I am looking forward to learning what I have done wrong.

This is more about my list:

```
protected final int MAXSIZE=10;
    protected Object [] list;
    protected int index;
    protected int curPos;

    public List()
    {
        list = new Object[MAXSIZE];
        for(int i = 0;i<MAXSIZE; i++)
        {
            list[i]=new Object();
        }
        index = 0;
        curPos = 0;
    }

    public List(int size)
    {
        list = new Object[size];
        for(int i = 0;i<size; i++)
        {
            list[i]=new Object();
        }
        index = 0;
        curPos = 0;
    }
```

adding elements

```
public void tryAdd(Object thing)//adds Object to index, increment index. if full, it deques first
    {
        if(isFull())
        {
            deque();
            setElement(thing,index-1);
        }
        else
        {
            setElement(thing,index);
            index++;
        }
    }

public void setElement(Object setWhat, int which) //assigns a specific element with the parameters
    {
        list[which] = setWhat;
    }
```

Also UserList:

```
public UserList(int size){super(size);}
```

Comment: Java uses polymorphism, so if the object is actually a type of User it will call the User's equals method. Can you show what your `list` array is and how it gets populated?

Comment: Okay I just editted in more details about list, and how it adds new elements.

Comment: One thing you should do is add `@Override` to the `equals` method. This would have showed you that you weren't actually overriding `equals`, but rather you were creating a new `equals` method.

Comment: For example, if I were to call my created equals() method something else like checkEquals(), could I just bypass Java thinking that I'm trying to call the Object equals() method?

Comment: Yes. What you were doing before is called method overloading (same method name, different parameters) - essenitally making another method which you never called. Now you are overriding it (providing your own implementation for a method of a superclass).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I believe it's calling the `Object.equals` method (which actually just checks if they're the exact same object) (every object is a subclass of `Object`).

This is because you're calling

```
list[i].equals(obj)
```

where `obj` is of type `Object` (even though it's actual type is `User`).

Having your `equals` method override `Object.equals` should work:

```
@Override
public boolean equals(Object other)
{
    User user = (User)other;
    if(user.getName().equals(name) && user.getId().equals(id))
        return true;
    else
        return false;
}
```

An alternative that should work is changing the type of the input parameter of `isThere` to `User`.

Comment: I just tried your suggestion and it worked like a charm. The only thing I had to change was to cast the object "other" as a (User) and not an (Object). It would give me error that I can't convert from Object to User. Thank you all so much for your help. I didn't know the fix would be so simple.